# MimeType Extraction from shell32

Tags: c#, mime-types

Would it be possible to extract the mimetype by importing shell32.dll in C#? Can anyone help me on this?

For example: for pdf it should retrieve -Adobe Acrobat Document

I could be able to extract using regkeys, but I'm looking for a way to extract using shell32.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really the MIME type but you can use this :

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetFileInfo.html

With SHGFI_TYPENAME in the uFlags parameter, it should return what you meant in your question. It didn't try it, let us know.

Comment: Thanks Speps , I could able to get the typeName ..Thanks a ton :)

Comment: in hope of nyone finds this useful..

uint flags = SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | size | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_TYPENAME ;

 SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, out info, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHFILEINFO)), flags);

string typeName = info.szTypeName;

Answer (score 1):

C# calls into native DLLs using P/Invoke.  If there is a function or set of functions exposed in shell32 that does what you want, there is almost certainly an example for it on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/)